# How to set up latest Angular (v15) with Bootstrap (v5) with .scss files

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5

How do you set up Angular with bootstrap and SASS (.scss files)?

Answer (score 0):

1. The following will set up [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io). This will allow you to use widgets, but not to use bootstrap conventionally (applying bootstrap classes to elements)

**Enter in CLI:**

```bash
ng new my-ng-bootstrap-app # Create angular app. Choose routing and SCSS options
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap # add bootstrap (see notes at bottom of this answer for how bootstrap is added to app)
ng generate component my-flex # Create a new component to test bootstrap's flex styles
ng serve # Run the Angular server
```

This will cause an error in later versions of Angular (I think from v14 onwards). Resolve this by replacing:

**./src/styles.scss**

```js
// @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
// Replace above line with
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Now that bootstrap is set up, we can go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/ and copy the code.

**src/app/my-flex/my-flex.component.html**

```html
  <!-- Replace the code in here with the example code from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#example -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**src/app/app.component.html**

```html
<!-- Delete all previous code -->
<app-my-flex></app-my-flex>
```

And that should be everything working. You can check the developer tools in your browser to see that the rendered DOM elements have bootstrap styles applied.

2. In order to use bootstrap conventionally, follow these directions:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75056081/11664580

---

**(FYI) `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` adds the following to:**

**src/styles.scss**

```js
/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```