# How to use bootstrap (v5) conventionally in Angular (v15)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

I've set up Bootstrap with Angular using the following commands, based on the [ng-bootstrap.github.io docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started):

```bash
ng new my-ng-bootstrap-app # Create angular app. Choose routing and SCSS options
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap # add bootstrap (see notes at bottom of this answer for how bootstrap is added to app)
ng generate component my-flex # Create a new component to test bootstrap's flex styles
ng serve # Run the Angular server
```

(I've detailed the full set-up method here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75039099/11664580)

This allows me to use bootstrap widgets, but when I try to use Bootstrap conventionally, nothing happens - eg:

```html
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        My Button
      </button>
```

The above doesn't apply any styles, even though I have set up as per the `ng-bootstrap` instructions.

What's the best way to apply bootstrap styles to my Angular app? I've got it working by simply adding a `link` element with the `href` to my `app.component.html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Or should I follow other guidance and install with `npm install bootstrap`?

Comment: You need to add `bootstrap` as per `ng-bootstrap` guideline because it will improve your application performance as well. So you install `bootstrap` using `npm install bootstrap`

Comment: When I install as per the `ng-bootstrap` docs, and then add the `link` with bootstrap `href` as per the bootstrap docs it works. Are you saying I should also run `npm i bootstrap` because it will boost performance?

Comment: Yes, it will boost your application performance because its better to call style locally rather than third party website.

Comment: @HardikSolanki, **not** install boostrap, you only need bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going with `npm install bootstrap`

then after installing in `angular.json` file search for

styles and add the path like...

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
]
```

you can copy the relavent path from `node_module > bootstrap > dist > css > bootstrap.min.css` or you can copy `node_module > bootstrap > dist > css > bootstrap.css`

in `angular.json` there are 2 styles, given path in both styles.

then it should work perfectly I guess.

Comment: **NOT** install bootstrap. You only need bootstrap.css. Download bootstrap, copy the bootstrap.min.css in a folder to your app and add it in styles.

Comment: So this means I don't need to use the `href` inside the `<link>` element in my HTML. What's the advantage of using your above method over using the `<link>` method?

Comment: So this means I don't need to use the `href` inside the `<link>` element in my HTML. What's the advantage of using your above method over using the `<link>` method?

Comment: @JimmyTheCode no need to link to any external bootstrap links once you have installed ```npm install bootstrap``` and the given the path in ```angular.json``` file, you can directly use bootstrap classes to give designs to your HTMLelements/code.