# Bootstrap 5.3.1 Carousel not working in Angular 15

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to implement a carousel in my home page, I feel like I'm not missing anything but I clearly am, the first image as well as the text and arrows show up but they don't work, I have Bootstrap properly imported through my module.js file and angular.json and I've already made a navigation bar with it so I know it's working properly

carousel HTML

```
<div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#mainCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#mainCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#mainCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="/../assets/grey1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/../assets/grey2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="/../assets/grey3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#mainCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#mainCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/params/css/fonts.googleapis.min.css",
              "styles.css"
            ],
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

the carousel should work considering i copied the code from bootstrap's official site and made sure I selected the version that I have installed

Comment: Please look at this issue, it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75055737/how-to-use-bootstrap-v5-conventionally-in-angular-v15

Comment: This issue may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75055737/how-to-use-bootstrap-v5-conventionally-in-angular-v15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be including jQuery and the bootstrap JS in an Angular project.

Those libraries directly manipulate the DOM in a way that Angular will not know about, and Angular needs to be in full control of your application.  It will cause you all kinds of conflicts and problems if you do this.

Instead, you should remove those linked JS files and use an Angular component library instead.  I recommend this one: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/

Remember, when you are working with Angular projects, you need to do things "the angular way" - meaning you can't work around how Angular works. Angular needs to control your application state and the HTML rendering.  If you try to use jQuery or anything like that it will not work properly.

Comment: ngx-bootstrap did work but it requires so many extra steps and it's own specific implementation, i'll settle on it for now, thanks

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's kinda just how it goes. But a lot of that was probably learning how it works, and now you are familiar with it for the next time you need to use it